# Copy files between docker machines

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to copy the files from the default docker-machine to a new docker-machine I have created. I am doing this because the default docker-machine has an abundance of hidden images which I do not feel like deleting by ID, and I have not found any documentation on how to remove these said images.

I am using the command `docker-machine scp default:<path to docker-machine> new:<path to newly created docker-machine>`

After the command it exits with code 1. Anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> the default docker-machine has an abundance of hidden images which I do not feel like deleting by ID

Those looks like dangling images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

Note: `docker scp` does not exist. [`docker-machine scp`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/scp/) does.

```
docker-machine scp default:/home/docker/foo.txt .
```

That assume you did first:

```
docker-machine ssh new
cd <path to newly created docker-machine>
```

Comment: yea meant to type docker-machine scp. That was a typo on my part. I will try this when I get back to my computer. Thanks!

Comment: But you need to ssh to the destination machine first.

Comment: Ok, as for removing the dangling images, I am getting back an error that says "rmi requires a minimum of 1 argument. Any suggestions?"

Comment: @M.Howell It just means you do not have any dangling images, so there is nothing to remove.